# Django IntegerField returning string(!) - how to coerce to int?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have an IntegerField declared as below on a model:

```
amount = models.IntegerField()
```

When accessing it, it sometimes returns a string. The proximate cause for this is that it has had a string assigned to it. So far, so unmysterious. It also returns a string even after it has been saved.

This strikes me as a little surprising: it would be nice if IntegerField coerced its value to an integer on assignment (or, at the latest, on save), so the user could rely on it being an integer.

(My application uses sqlite.)

**Is there a way to make IntegerField only return ints? Or do I have to create a custom field to do this?**

Comment: Try pulling the object from the database again, and see if it's an int then. If I recall, going into the database, Django's ORM will call repr() on objects - thus why it appears to be saving normally.

Comment: @NathanHoad: Thanks. I will try that, but it's not entirely satisfactory :(

Comment: Downvoter: Care to reveal yourself?

Comment: @Marcin yeah, it's a little annoying when this sort of thing happens. The quickest fix would be to find the source of the string and turn it into an int - to me it would indicate there's something amiss earlier in the validation that should be picking this up.

Comment: what's wrong with good old `amount = int(models.IntegerField())`? :)

Comment: @NathanHoad: Agreed, and indeed I've fixed it in that way.

Comment: @Kimvais: I'd prefer to express that in a pointfree style ;)

Comment: @Kimvais there's nothing wrong with coercing it back to an int, per se, it's just dealing with a symptom, not the root problem.

Comment: @Marcin I've added it as an answer for future readers, if you'd care to mark it correct :)

Comment: @NathanHoad: I always wait a day to accept answers, in case something even better is posted!

Comment: @Marcin Sounds fair to me! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the reason this is happening is that Django performs relevant coercions on fields at save, but doesn't reflect value changes back on the original model because it can't be done without querying the database again.

The quickest fix (and easiest, in the long run) for this kind of problem is to find the source of the string and turn it into an int - to me it would indicate there's something amiss earlier in the validation that should be picking this up.

Comment: My issue was that the value came from the form as a string and was saved to a new object. Then using that new object, I was trying to do math but the object returned a string even thou in the database it was an Integer.