# (can only concatenate str (not "int") to str) this is the error i am getting why is it saying that i am trying to add string and int?

Tags: python, django

[image]i am following django official documentation tutorial t make a poll app i am currently stuck on part 4.So when i select one of the choices it shows an error (can only concatenate str (not "int") to str).
I cant understand  am i trying to add a string to integer where is the problem in the code

please herlp here is my code:

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Choice, Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)


def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})


def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the question voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

**models.py**

```
import datetime
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: line 35 of views.py which says         selected_choice.votes += 1

Comment: Django's traceback includes a "Local Vars" section for each level, expand that and you can see *exactly* what `selected_choice` contains.

Comment: it shows               selected_choice <Choice: The sky>       but i wanna incremet 1 to selected_choice.votes

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot, you can remove your concatenation and insert `print(type(variable_name))` throughout your code to print the variable type to see where python is assigning the `string` type to your variable.

Including the full error message will be helpful for any additional troubleshooting.

It looks like django doesn't coerce the value to an integer, so I'm going to suspect that's where your problem is. `votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)` from your models.py.  There is a related question here which also suggests troubleshooting similar to what I've suggested. Then to explicitly convert that value to an integer. [Django IntegerField returning string(!) - how to coerce to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395106/django-integerfield-returning-string-how-to-coerce-to-int)

Comment: i cant do that as i am incrementing look at line 35 of views.py which says         selected_choice.votes += 1
    thats the source of problem

Comment: Yes, that's the source of the problem. Remove `+= 1` to avoid the error and print the type of the variable to see where it's being assigned the `string` type.

Comment: @Naveednaseer I updated my answer. Please see the additional information.